# Can't assign the variable of an Int to the UILabel

Tags: ios, swift

I can't assign the variable of an Int to the UILabel, how can I fix this?

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var CoinCounterInt: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var CoinCounter: UILabel!
var coins = 0
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func Clicker(sender: AnyObject) {
    coins += 1
    CoinCounterInt = "\(coins)"
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the the string to the text property of the label:
`CoinCounterInt.text = "\(coins)"`

Comment: @NilsGarland I guess because you didn't look much around.